# Fitting items next to trees on the page

Tags: trees

I want to be able to put items to the left or right of the tree structure in the following example. How can I do that? At the moment each tree occupies a line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.X X Y ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because the `tikzpicture` is an hbox, simply `before \begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.X X Y ]
\end{tikzpicture} after` will place text to the left and right of the tree.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It didn't seem to work before. ;)

Comment: If you had blank lines above/below the `tikzpicture`, it would interpret it as a paragraph boundary and surrounding text would therefore be above and below, as opposed to either side.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

Just some pictures...

[image: bark of the shark]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat,forest}
\begin{document}
  The base of the following tree is aligned with the baseline \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.south)]
    \Tree [.X X Y ]
  \end{tikzpicture}, whereas the top of the next is aligned with the baseline \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]{\Tree [.X X Y ]} and the baseline is aligned with the centre of the next one \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]{\Tree [.X X Y ]}.

  \forestset{
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    mycomma/.style={%
      before drawing tree={
        content/.wrap value={##1,},
        typeset node
      }
    },
    baseline/.append style={text=red},
  }
  Any node of a tree may be aligned with the baseline quite easily.
  For example,
  \begin{forest}[A, baseline, mycomma [B [D] [E]] [C [F] [G]]]\end{forest}
  \begin{forest}[A [B, baseline, mycomma [D] [E]] [C, mycomma [F] [G]]]\end{forest}
  \begin{forest}[A [B [D, baseline, mycomma] [E, mycomma]] [C [F, mycomma] [G, mycomma]]]\end{forest}
  and   \begin{forest}[A [B [D] [E [H., baseline]]] [C [F] [G]]]\end{forest}

  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[c]{.35\textwidth}
    This is some information

    about the tree

    on the right

    which is quite

    upright

    --- for a tree.
  \end{minipage}}
  \fbox{\begin{forest}
    [A[B[C]]]
  \end{forest}}
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}
    This is the weft

    from the left

    --- not the warp

    or the gawp.
  \end{minipage}}
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{.25\textwidth}
    Far on the side,

    safe from the tide,

    shark of the bark.
  \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```